# Why is every answer in this question a Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion, questions

So looking for a solution to a problem i have for a web menu needing to disappear when there is a click anywhere else and i came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

What i find weird is that every answer is a Community Wiki, 3 i found were made [into](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14967514/revisions) [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14927422/revisions) [Wikis](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13877279/revisions) by Estelle Chvl which seems even weirder, well to me it seems weird because i normally only see Community Wikis on Meta

so i am wondering what is the history behind this question which cased every answer to become a Community Wiki and if this kind of things has happened more than just once

Answer (score 15):

For many years, we had rules in place that caused questions to be automatically converted to a community wiki. One of those rules was if the question reached 30 answers. The user mentioned posted the 30th answer to the question, which caused the question to get converted to a wiki, and subsequently all the answers under it.

These automatic conversion rules were [abandoned in April 2014](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/).